# ‘sqlite3_prepare_v2’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: sqlite, cmake

Since the version of `sqlite3` is too old, I installed an alternative new version of `sqlite3`. The new version was installed in these path:

```
/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include
/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib
```

I adapted [this FindSQLite3.cmake](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake) and used it in `cmake` to find the new `sqlite3`. The output of `MESSAGE` showed that `cmake` could find `includes` and `libs` of the new version:

```
-- SQLite3 include: /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include
-- SQLite3 lib: /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.so
-- SQLite3 IS USED
```

When I installed my project, the error `‘sqlite3_prepare_v2’ was not declared in this scope` occured. But `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is include in the new version, it should be declared. I think the possible reason is `cmake` could not find the new version and find the old version instead. Any help? Thank you in advance!

My `FindSQLite3.cmake`:

```
if (SQLITE3_LIBRARIES AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  # in cache already
  set(SQLITE3_FOUND TRUE)
else (SQLITE3_LIBRARIES AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  # use pkg-config to get the directories and then use these values
  # in the FIND_PATH() and FIND_LIBRARY() calls
  if (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION} EQUAL 2 AND ${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} EQUAL 6)
    include(UsePkgConfig)
    pkgconfig(sqlite3 _SQLITE3_INCLUDEDIR _SQLITE3_LIBDIR _SQLITE3_LDFLAGS _SQLITE3_CFLAGS)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Test ${_SQLITE3_INCLUDEDIR} ${_SQLITE3_LIBDIR} ${_SQLITE3_LDFLAGS} ${_SQLITE3_CFLAGS}")
  else (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION} EQUAL 2 AND ${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} EQUAL 6)
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    #MESSAGE(STATUS "TEST-1")
    if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
      pkg_check_modules(_SQLITE3 REQUIRED sqlite-3.11)
    #MESSAGE(STATUS "TEST-2")
    endif (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  endif (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION} EQUAL 2 AND ${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} EQUAL 6)

   find_path(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES
      sqlite3.h
    PATHS
      ${_SQLITE3_INCLUDEDIR}
      /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include
  )

  find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARY
    NAMES
      sqlite3
    PATHS
      ${_SQLITE3_LIBDIR}
      /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib
  )

  if (SQLITE3_LIBRARY)
    set(SQLITE3_FOUND TRUE)
  endif (SQLITE3_LIBRARY)

  set(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR}  
  )

#MESSAGE(STATUS "${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR}")

  if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
    set(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES
      ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES}
      ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}
    )
#MESSAGE(STATUS "${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES} ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}")
  endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)

  if (SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS AND SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
     set(SQLITE3_FOUND TRUE)
  endif (SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS AND SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)

  if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
    if (NOT Sqlite3_FIND_QUIETLY)
#      MESSAGE(STATUS "Found Sqlite3: ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES}")
    endif (NOT Sqlite3_FIND_QUIETLY)
  else (SQLITE3_FOUND)
    if (Sqlite3_FIND_REQUIRED)
      MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Sqlite3")
    endif (Sqlite3_FIND_REQUIRED)
  endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)

  # show the SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS and SQLITE3_LIBRARIES variables only in the advanced view
  mark_as_advanced(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)

endif (SQLITE3_LIBRARIES AND SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Code lines in My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include")
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib")

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/iRoot-make/cmake")

FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED)

MESSAGE(STATUS "SQLite3 include: ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "SQLite3 lib: ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES}")

IF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "SQLite3 IS USED")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SQLITE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "SQLite3 IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)

aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${DIR_SRCS})

#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

# set location of binary generated by the program, 
# here PROJECT_BINARY_DIR = DIR OF build
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# set location of lib generated by the program
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

install(TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

The `sqlite3.h` is included in my header:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

and `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is used in the corresponding cpp file.

Comment: Show us how you **use** results of `find_package` in the `CMakeLists.txt` for compile your program. And your program, of course.

Comment: Hi again @Tsyvarev I have updated the post.

Comment: `find_package(SQLite3)` sets variable `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS`, but you use `SQLITE_INCLUDE_DIRS` (without `3`) for `include_directories()`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry for the mistake, I changed it to `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS`, and re-installed the project, but hundreds of error `undefined reference` occured.

Comment: So you need to uncomment `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Still got hundreds of `undefined reference`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107804/discussion-between-just-rookie-and-tsyvarev).

Answer (score 0):

Set `SQLITE3_LIBRARIES` and `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS` in your `CMakeCache.txt` (or with cmake-gui) such that they point to the desired library version. Delete `SQLITE3_FOUND` and `SQLITE3_DEFINITIONS` and rerun CMake.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, how to set `SQLITE3_LIBRARIES` and `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS` and how to delete `SQLITE3_FOUND` and `SQLITE3_DEFINITIONS`? Could you explain your solution in detail? Thank you.

Comment: Just as I described: You can use cmake-gui and you see all variables and their values. Or you can edit CMakeCache.txt in your build directory.